# ¿Como encriptar contraseña en java?

Tags: java, string

Tengo que hacer una clase `Password` y que ingrese por teclado una contraseña por consola y a su vez en la consola se debe ver la contraseña con asteriscos y luego re ingresar la contraseña para verificar que sean iguales.

No se si java tiene algún tipo de `input type = password` como html , para que cada vez que quiera usar una contraseña me las escriba con ese símbolo , he descargado librerías pero solo devuelve un encriptado alfanumérico , como podría hacerlo?

Trate de hacer algo super sencillo pero no funciona ya que no me reemplaza lo que escribo en el momento que lo ingreso :

```
    package password_encriptado;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class PasswordEncriptado {
    public static void main(String [] args) {


    Scanner t = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese contraseña:");
        String contraseña=t.next().replace("a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|u","*");
        System.out.println("Ingrese nuevamente la contraseña:");
        Stringverificacion=t.next().replace("a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|u","*");

        if(contraseña.equals(verificacion)) {
            System.out.println("ingreso la contraseña de forma correcta");
        }else {
            System.err.println("error! debe coincidir las contraseñas");
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Desde consola no se puede, tendrías que crear una interfaz gráfica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siempre puedes utilizar la opción **readPassword** que viene con la libreria **java.io.Console**. Eso si, no muestra asteriscos.

Un ejemplo de muestra:

```
import java.io.Console;
public class ConsolePassword {

    public void passwordExample() {        
        Console console = System.console();
        if (console == null) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't get Console instance");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        console.printf("Testing password%n");
        char[] passwordArray = console.readPassword("Enter your secret password: ");
        char[] secondPasswordArray = console.readPassword("Enter your secret password again: ");

        if((new String(passwordArray)).equals(new String(secondPasswordArray))) {
            System.out.println("ingreso la contraseña de forma correcta");
        }else {
            System.err.println("error! debe coincidir las contraseñas");
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ConsolePassword().passwordExample();
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva.
PD: **En algunos IDES no funciona** pero lo hace bien si pruebas el ejemplo en linea de comandos compilando con javac y ejecutando con java.

Comment: Muchas Gracias es una muy buena opcion :D , Saludos!